# Unable to get Eclipse to recognize binaries using ProcessBuilder located on $PATH on mac os x

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, eclipse-classpath

I have just switched over to working on a mac and I am trying to determine why I am unable to get `Eclipse` to recognize the binary I am trying to run via a `ProcessBuilder`.

I have tried to run it both as a `Java Application` in `Eclipse` and as a `TestNG` test.

If I compile the class with `java` and run it directly from the command line it will work but not through Eclipse which leads me to believe the configuration for the `$PATH` is not setup correctly in my `TestNG` configuration.

**Question**

I am sure this is a configuration issue within Eclipse but after searching for a day and coming up short I wanted to post for some help.  I have tried to set `$PATH` on the configuration but it does not seem to work.

Thank you

**Update /Answer**

It turned out that the `PATH` I had set on the shell shown below was not the same that `Java` had which I checked using the code below.  After verifying that I then added the proper path to my environment on the ProcessBuilder and executed the script as shown in the answer.

```
Map<String, String> env = processBuilder.environment();
        for (String key : env.keySet())
             System.out.println(key + ": " + env.get(key));

        Map<String, String> envs = processBuilder.environment();
        System.out.println("Path " + envs.get("PATH"));
        envs.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin");
        System.out.println("PATH " + envs.get("PATH"));
```

**Code**

```
        File logsDir = new File(logDirectory);
        if (!logsDir.exists()) {
            logsDir.mkdirs();
        }

        // run process directly
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command("appium");

        processBuilder.redirectError(new File(logsDir, "appiumError.txt"));
        processBuilder.redirectOutput(new File(logsDir, "appiumOutput.txt"));

        process = processBuilder.start();
```

**Output** (it cannot find `node` to run appium hence the `No such file or directory`)

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "appium": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at AppiumService.startAppium(AppiumService.java:77)
```

**Path** (The bin for `node` and `appium` is in /usr/local/bin)

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
/usr/local/opt/ant/bin:/usr/local/opt/maven/bin:
/usr/local/opt/gradle/bin
```

Comment: do a `System.getenv()` and print it out to see if the PATH-variable of the java-process is actually the one you showed us here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PATH variable of the java-process might be explicitly set by Eclipse not containing the paths you need. You can call the command using the absolute path to the corresponding directory or you might try using a shell to start the process by creating the process with

```
processBuilder.command("/bin/sh", "-c", "appium");
```

Comment: Thank you.  It turns out my PATH was not what I was expecting.  I added an update above for any others that may come to this page wanting to verify your path matches what you expect.  After that I set it as I needed it and used your solution for starting it as a script.