# Programmatically get full paths of external programs from within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to get the full path of system programs using the following Java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PathExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("which", "mvn");
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled and run from the command line, the expected output is printed out:

> /usr/local/bin/mvn

However, when run within Eclipse, I get exit value 1 with the following output:

> null

After a bit of research, I found a similar question, with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48831940/3527464) suggesting to start a shell to run the previous command:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "which mvn")
```

Unfortunately the command still fails with a `null` output. Note that on a Windows machine simply using *new ProcessBuilder("where", "mvn")* has the desired effect.

How can I determine the path of programs programmatically from within Eclipse?

Comment: What operating system? This code runs OK on macOS

Comment: Well, funnily enough, it's macOS as well for me. Slightly old version, El Capitan, but I wouldn't expect that to matter too much. Does it work as well for you with executables stored in less "standard" locations, for instance a Ruby gems? Another observation is that when I run the command with zsh shell ("/bin/zsh", "-c", "which mvn"), it fails but I do get a "mvn not found" error rather than "null".

Comment: This code returns `null` for anything that isn't on the current PATH. `which` only searches the path.

Comment: So I'm guessing that there's no way to do what I'm asking for? Eclipse will generally not be started with the PATH the user defined in their profile in macOS.

Comment: I'm also surprised `null` is returned rather than a helpful error message. It's as if `which` itself failed rather than reporting that it did not find the command.

Comment: The `process.waitFor()` call returns the 'exit value' of the program, this is 0 when 'which' found the program and 1 when it didn't - you get null when the exit code is 1. When running a program from Eclipse you can specify environment variables in the 'Run Configuration' for the program

Comment: In fact, the reason it prints `null` is because a different command is being used in the `sh` shell, `/usr/bin/which`, and that seems to be its behaviour. When invoking through `zsh`, `which` is a shell builtin, printing messages such as "mvn not found". That's one bit of confusion solved. Back to the core problem, as I'm building a plugin, making users alter their launch configurations isn't a great experience. However, passing the login option `-l` to `bash` seems to do the trick: `new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-l", "-c", "which mvn")`. Will experiment some more and wrap up in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I managed to programmatically get full paths of external programs from within Eclipse with the following command:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-l", "-c", "which mvn")
```

The `-l` (or `--login`) flag is the key to the solution. According to the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell
>
> [...]
>
> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>   and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable.

In other words, this will allow the external programme to pick up the `PATH` variable from one of the standard locations, even though it may be set to a different value in Eclipse itself.